# PgSQL: Assigning a column value to a variable makes query parameter unbound

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

When running the code below:

```
drop table if exists demo;
drop table if exists demo_test;
drop table if exists demo_result;

create table demo as select md5(v::text) from generate_series(1, 1000000) v;
create index on demo (md5 text_pattern_ops);
analyze demo;

create table demo_test 
    as select left(md5(v::text), 5) || '%' as "patt" from generate_series(2000000, 2000010) v;

create table demo_result (row text);

load 'auto_explain';
set auto_explain.log_min_duration to 0;
set auto_explain.log_analyze to true;
set auto_explain.log_nested_statements to true;

do $$
declare
    row record;
pattern text;
begin
    for row in select patt from demo_test loop
        pattern = row.patt;  -- <--- CRUCIAL LINE
        insert into demo_result select * from demo where md5 like pattern;
    end loop;
end$$;
```

PostgreSQL generates the following query plan:

```
2017-10-02 17:03:48 CEST [18038-23] app=psql barczynski@barczynski LOG:  duration: 0.021 ms  plan:
        Query Text: insert into demo_result select * from demo where md5 like pattern
        Insert on demo_result  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=100 width=33) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=0 loops=1)
          ->  Index Only Scan using demo_md5_idx on demo  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=100 width=33) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)
                Index Cond: ((md5 ~>=~ '791cc'::text) AND (md5 ~<~ '791cd'::text))
                Filter: (md5 ~~ '791cc%'::text)
                Heap Fetches: 1
```

But after removing `pattern` variable, and inlining `row.patt` in `where` condition:

```
insert into demo_result select * from demo where md5 like row.patt;
```

PostgreSQL treats the parameter as bind:

```
2017-10-02 17:03:02 CEST [17901-23] app=psql barczynski@barczynski LOG:  duration: 89.636 ms  plan:
        Query Text: insert into demo_result select * from demo where md5 like row.patt
        Insert on demo_result  (cost=0.00..20834.00 rows=5000 width=33) (actual time=89.636..89.636 rows=0 loops=1)
          ->  Seq Scan on demo  (cost=0.00..20834.00 rows=5000 width=33) (actual time=47.255..89.628 rows=1 loops=1)
                Filter: (md5 ~~ $4)
                Rows Removed by Filter: 999999
```

I understand that the latter plan employs sequential scan, because PostgreSQL assumes that bind parameters start with wildcards.

My question is why the extra assignment switches bind parameter on and off?

Comment: Question: Are you getting the expected rows in the table with both methods? Just making sure we're not getting unintended results due to conflicting with a reserved word or something odd like that.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the same rows with both versions.

Comment: Have you tried casting both to text to see if that changes anything? At this point, I'd be doing trial and error to attempt to discern the cause of the different execution plans.

Comment: The reason for different execution plans was explained below by Gary. My question is why assigning row to variable turns off bind parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the data available to the optimizer at the time it looks at the query.

With the first query, the bound parameter is available for the optimizer to look at.  So it sees that there is no wildcard and it knows that the index can be used.

```
insert into demo_result select * from demo where md5 like '791cc%';
```

The second query has no idea what the pattern will look like so its not able to make the assumption that the index is any good.

I suspect that if you had a pattern with a leading wildcard '%791cc' you would see the same query plan being used for both approaches as a seq_scan would be used for both.

Comment: I agree that that's how it looks like, but `row` is also a variable. Why PostgreSQL can optimize `text`, but can't `record` type?